# How to attach input filed to another in Angular 2 only if it's pristine?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular2-ngmodel

I have two input fields:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="og_title" name="og_title" value="{{ title }}">
```

I want to make the `og_title` field to equal to `title` until og_title is pristine.

How can I do this in `Angular 2` (Angular 7)

Comment: whatever you tried it happening the same right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better if you use Reactive forms instead of two way binding with ngModel, but still this would work :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title" (input)="titleChanged()">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="og_title" name="og_title">
```

and in the TS file :

```
titleChanged(){
 if(<code to check if og_title is pristine>){
  this.og_title = this.title;
 }
}
```

replace the `<code to check if og_title is pristine>` with logic that includes name of the form and pristine condition of input field

Answer (score 1):

you can assign to the ngModel

HTML

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title" (input)="assignToModel($event)">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="og_title" name="og_title" value="{{ title }}">
```

TS:

```
assignToModel(event){
this.og_title = event.target.value;
}
```